# C array size declaration means nothing?

Tags: c, arrays

```
char arr1 [0];
arr1[50] = 'A';

char arr2 [0] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; //gives compiler warning
```

Why do the above compile normally?

And how come only the second gives me a warning?

Comment: one is a declaration, the other is a runtime error. (In reverse order, obviously)

Comment: For the first, you're using a compiler that supports zero-length arrays as an extension, as it is not part of the standard and will fail with any strict-standard-conforming toolchain. Addressing the 50th element of a zero-length array is the C language allowing the engineer to shoot themselves in the foot with undefined behavior. Its really as simple as that. For the second, the warning (too many values in initializer) is rather telling, and should be included as part of the question, as always. And as a consequence therein, "compile normally" seems somewhat inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

The first one compiles normally because the compiler will typically not realize that `a[50] = 0` is attempting to assign a value outside the array allocated memory. The behavior at runtime is undefined: it may crash, terminate the program, format your harddrive, or not do anything at all.

The second one gives a warning because the array initializer on the right does not match the array declaration on the left. It would be like writing `int x = "a string"`.

Answer (score 1):

Both declarations should give you a compile time error since declaring an array of length `0` is a "constraint violation" a type of error that any compiler *must* capture if it is conforming to the C standard.

```
char arr2 [0] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

Has an additional constraint violation, namely that there are more initializers than elements in the array. Your compiler only seems to capture that one.

In contrast to that

```
arr1[50] = 'A';
```

is just run time behavior that is undefined by the standard and the compiler can do anything that pleases with it. A good compiler could also easily detect that one.

In summary, you should perhaps look into getting yourself a better, more recent compiler.

Answer (score 0):

"char arr2 [0] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};" would give you an error since you are declaring arr2 as an array of zero element and initializing it with 5 elements. Most likely the compiler would complain/warn you of having excess elements in the array initializer. You can either do "char arr2[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};" and C would **implicitly** figure out the storage OR you can **explicitly** specify the number of elements: "char arr2[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};"

Also, "arr1[50] = 'A';" is a bad idea when you are delcaring arr1 as an array of size zero: "char arr1 [0];". Just declare it so that it can have enough elements to include the value that you are adding at index 50.